# WordPress: How To Display the_title as a Link

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm having trouble displaying a title as a link in a WordPress function.

If I code it like this:

```
function my_popular_posts($count) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => $count));
    if($query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
**THIS LINE --> echo '<li><a href='.get_permalink().'> .the_title(). </a></li>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo "<p>No popular posts found<p>"; 
    }
}
```

At run-time, the link displays as ".the_title()"

If I code it this way:

```
echo '<li><a href='.get_permalink().'>'.the_title().'</a></li>';
```

It will display the title, but not as a link.

Any Ideas? Your help will be appreciated.

Thnx!

Comment: @cale_b  Your answers were patially correct.  I had the double quotes during one of my edits but some how I forgot to put them back in. this was the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22182574/742030

Comment: the_title() is self echoing, it will echo itself so when used inside an echo its going to break, use `get_the_title()` if using within an echo statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`the_title` output contents itself. You need to use `get_the_title()` which returns the content

Try this:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thx! I had that b4 but i was missing the double quotes.

Comment: It did in combination to the double quotes -  have to wait 2 more min b4 I can check it as the answer - Thnx Again!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing quotation marks on that line.

Note the addition of the closing quotes:

```
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href=' . get_permalink() . '>' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
```

Additionally, you markup should include quotations around the link url, as edited below:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: I upped you bcoz I did need the double quotes - However, I did have that originally and it didn't work.  I retried both of your answer but neither worked too.

Comment: the_title() is self echoing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use double quotes for `href=""` to let the link work

```
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
```

[**Learn more here**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: I upped you bcoz I did need the double quotes - However, I did have that originally and it didn't work.

Comment: @Andaero Try to `echo get_permalink();` does it print the link correctly?

Comment: the_title() is self echoing.